# It's working in Localhost but it's not working in my Hosting? (youtube-mp3.org link)

Tags: php, hash, time, localhost, hosting

I'm installing this Link: [youtube-mp3.org download class](https://github.com/victorsa/youtubetomp3)

youtubetomp3.php //class php

```
    <?php
 class YoutubeToMP3 {
    const DOWNLOAD = 1;
    const LINK = 2;

    /**
     * Obtem o link de download do MP3 de um video do YouTube
     * @param  string  $url    URL do video no YouTube
     * @param  integer $action Acão que será executada com o link (YoutubeToMP3::DOWNLOAD,  YoutubeToMP3::LINK) 
     * @return mixed           Quando o parametro $action for definido como YoutubeToMP3::DOWNLOAD redireciona 
     *                         para o download do arquivo, quando YoutubeToMP3::LINK traz o link como retorno
     */
    public static function get($url, $action = self::LINK) {
        $currentTime = time();
        $videoId = self::getYoutubeId($url);

        $itemInfoUrl = "http://www.youtube-mp3.org/a/itemInfo/?video_id={$videoId}&ac=www&t=grp&r={$currentTime}";
        $itemInfo = self::httpRequest($itemInfoUrl);

        $sequence = $videoId . $currentTime;
        $requestId = $itemInfo['h'];
        $cc = self::cc($sequence);

        $MP3URL = "http://www.youtube-mp3.org/get?ab=128&video_id={$videoId}&h={$requestId}&r={$currentTime}.{$cc}";

        if ($action == self::DOWNLOAD):
            self::redirect($MP3URL);
        else:
            return $MP3URL;
        endif;
    }

    /**
     * Realiza uma requisição do tipo GET para uma url dada
     * @param  string $url Url que será requisitada
     * @return array       Array associativo do JSON retornado
     */
    private static function httpRequest ($url) {
        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        // Clear response string
        $jsonString = str_replace(array('info = ', ';'), '', $result);
        $parsedJSON = json_decode($jsonString, true);

        return $parsedJSON;
    }

    /**
     * Obtem o ID do um video do YouTube a partir de uma URL
     * @param  string $url URL do video
     * @return mixed       String com o id caso seja uma URL válida ou false do contrário
     */
    private static function getYoutubeId ($url) {
        $pattern = '%^(?:https?://)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be/|youtube\.com(?:/embed/|/v/|.*v=))([\w-]{10,12})($|&).*$%x';
        $result = preg_match($pattern, $url, $matches);

        if ($result !== false):
            return $matches[1];
        endif;

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Gera uma sequencia necessária para a API do youtube-mp3.org
     * @param  string $a Id do video concatenado com o timestamp atual
     * @return string    Sequencia
     */
    private static function cc ($a) {
        $AM = 65521; 
        $c = 1; 
        $b = 0;
        $d; 
        $e;

        for ($e = 0; $e < strlen($a); $e++):
            $d = self::charCodeAt($a,$e);
        $c = ($c + $d) % $AM;
        $b = ($b + $c) % $AM;
        endfor;

        return $b << 16 | $c;
    }

    /**
     * Metodo utilitário
     */
    private static function charCodeAt($str, $i){
        return ord(substr($str, $i, 1));
    }

    /**
     * Header Redirect
     *
     * Header redirect in two flavors
     * For very fine grained control over headers, you could use the Output
     * Library's set_header() function.
     *
     * @param string $uri URL
     * @param string $method Redirect method  'auto', 'location' or 'refresh'
     * @param int    $code HTTP Response status code
     * @return void
     */
    private static function redirect ($uri = '', $method = 'auto', $code = NULL) {
        if (!preg_match('#^(\w+:)?//#i', $uri)) {
            $uri = site_url($uri);
        }

        if ($method === 'auto' && isset($_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE']) && strpos($_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'], 'Microsoft-IIS') !== FALSE) {
            $method = 'refresh';
        } elseif ($method !== 'refresh' && (empty($code) OR ! is_numeric($code))) {
            if (isset($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'], $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) && $_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] === 'HTTP/1.1') {
                $code = ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] !== 'GET')? 303 : 307;
            } else {
                $code = 302;
            }
        }

        switch ($method) {
            case 'refresh':
                header('Refresh:0;url='.$uri);
            break;
            default:
                header('Location: '.$uri, TRUE, $code);
            break;
        }
        exit;
    }
}
?>
```

//Using php

```
<?php 
include ('youtubetomp3.php');
echo $link = YoutubeToMP3::get('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tGa5-nojscY', YoutubeToMP3::DOWNLOAD);
?>
```

Could be the problems are these;

- a-) is it because youtube-mp3.org or my hosting ?
- b-) is it because $currentTime = time(); ?
- c-) is it because $requestId = $itemInfo['h']; ?

Comment: What is the problem? What errors do you get (check the logs!)? What do you expect it to do?

Comment: probably curl is not enabled or installed in your hosting, that's why you can't get it to work, you should check the logs to see errors.

Comment: is there any difference between your localhost and hosting with phpinfo();

Comment: @Burak, @Bart Friederichs (error dosyasında bunlar yazıyor) This My Error Log :
`PHP Warning:  curl_setopt() [<a href='function.curl-setopt'>function.curl-setopt</a>]: CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated when safe_mode is enabled or an open_basedir is set in /home/***/public_html/***.com/youtubetomp3.php on line 44
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to error in your logs as you mentioned in the comments, you need to set `safe_mode = Off` and remove the line about `open_base_dir` in your `php.ini` file. If you can't access to your `php.ini` file, then ask your hosting provider to do that.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of ip adress.Youtube-MP3.org use info.h in their download links.And info.h is generating for user's ip adress and download link is only belongs to connector user.So you cant share it with other users.Clearly, in website, server uses own ip adress and gets link from youtubemp3 for own ip adress and user can't use it.But in localhost server's and user's ip adress are same so php runs correctly.